# another mass assignment error for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've done this 10 times and every time I seem to run into some issue with nested forms. Here's what I have:

client controller:

```
  def new
    @client = Client.new
    @contact = @client.contacts.new
    @header = "New Client"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @client }
    end
  end
```

client class:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## ASSOCIATIONS ##
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoices

  ## ACCESSIBLE ##
  attr_accessible :name, :address_line_one, :address_line_two,
                      :contacts_attributes
  ## NESTED ATTRIBUTES ##
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
```

in the form:

```
  = form_for(@client) do |f|
    = f.fields_for(@contact) do |contact|
```

but i still get this error when submitting the form:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: contact
```

and the params:

```
"client"=>{"name"=>"23",
 "contact"=>{"name"=>"asdf",
 "email"=>"af@gmail.com"}},
 "commit"=>"Save"}
```

Comment: Have you tried :contact_attributes and accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact? I usually find its a naming convention issue, or having a db column that's named the same as the model.

Comment: i don't think that's it since it is a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
  @client.contacts.build
  @header = "New Client"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @client }
  end
end
```

And:

```
= form_for(@client) do |f|
  = f.fields_for(:contacts) do |contact|
```